# Python - make class decorator work on derived classes

Tags: python, oop, decorator

In the app we're developing using Django, in some cases we need to automatically assign permissions to users for some models, that has owners (there is no rule for field's name, it can be "user", "owner", "coach" etc., also there can by more than one field.) My solution is to create a decorator containing those fields names, that will be put before model definition, like this (not using django-specific code in samples):

```
@auto_assign_perms('owner', 'user')
class Test(Base):
    pass
```

Let's assume that `Base` is an abstract class deriving after Django's `Model` class, where I add functionality to assign permissions after object is saved. For now I only print a list of users assigned to the class. Below you can find code for the decorator and `Base` class:

```
class auto_assign_perms(object):
    def __init__(self, *users):
        self.users = users

    def __call__(self, cls):
        cls.owners.update(self.users)
        return cls


class Base(object):
    owners = set()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for owner in self.owners:
            print owner,
        print
```

And my models could look like this:

```
@auto_assign_perms('owner', 'user')
class Test(Base):
    pass

@auto_assign_perms('coach')
class Test2(Base):
    pass
```

The problem is that both child classes contains all three fields `('owner', 'user', 'coach')`, altough `print self.__class__.__name__` in `Base.save()` method properly shows "Test" or "Test2". I tried to add classmethod `get_owners()` in `Base` class and then iterating over its results, but it doesn't helps.
How can I solve this? Maybe I should use metaclasses (I don't get them yet)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the list of owners, not update:

```
class auto_assign_perms(object):
    def __init__(self, *users):
        self.users = users

    def __call__(self, cls):
        cls.owners = set(self.users) # <- here
        return cls

#some tests
@auto_assign_perms('owner', 'user')
class Test(Base):
    pass

@auto_assign_perms('coach')
class Test2(Base):
    pass


t = Test()
t.save()
t = Test2()
t.save()

>>> 
owner user
coach
```

Comment: My solution is similar to yours the only difference is that when doing `cls.owners = set(..)` a new class variable `owners` will be created dynamically in the derived classes and the `Base.owners` will not be changed which is IMO hacky because 1) most users will not expecting that and 2) `Base.owners` is useless, but good answer anyway :)

Comment: @mouad And you will have to repeat the line `owners = set()` again and again in every child class. Not very DRY. So that's the use of `Base.owners` - to define it once and inherit.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Programming is a domain where you can look for your code for hours and be unable to see an error or solution to it and another person can see it immediately :)

Comment: @DrTyrsa: Good point but if you are doing this IMO you should also remove `owners` class variable from Base class because it's misleading, and you are already setting the owners variable in the decorator (IMO i see the overwriting of class variable like this as an Anti-pattern), but again it will be for user that see the code `where is he setting the owners variable ?!!`. correct me if i'm wrong but good discussion this why i love SO :)

Comment: @mouad But you already have `owners` in `save()` method. So the question will be the same: where is he setting it? And as you can see there is an iteration over it. Imagine you forgot to insert the line in child class (or you don't want to decorate and even think about some owners). It will be error, if `Base` has no `owners`. And third: you can leave some useful comments when defining it in base class, and where do you put them if there is no such a variable? In constructor? Like `don't forget to define 'owners' when you inherit me or I will be a very sad class`?

Comment: IMHO owners should be defined in `Base`, because not all models will be decorated, so it's both easier to read (direct definition of set) and cleaner (no need to check for existance of `owners` eg via try/except block)

Comment: @uolot, @DrTyrsa: Your point was very good, i can't argue more you win but before i lift the white flag :) i posted one last example that i think is more elegant because i don't think that `owners` should be a class variable at all or maybe i'm way wrong, correct me if i'm wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `owners` as a class variable of `Base` so whenever you change `owners` the change will be seen in all the derived classes.

To fix that you should define the `owners` variable as class variable of the derived classes:

```
class Base(object):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for owner in self.owners:
            print owner,
        print

@auto_assign_perms('owner', 'user')
class Test(Base):
     owners = set()

@auto_assign_perms('coach')
class Test2(Base):
     owners = set()
```

Answer (score 0):

Call me paranoia but i find this solution more elegant and that because i don't think you need owners to be a class variable at all:

```
def auto_assign_perms(*users):

    def class_wrapper(cls):
        class ClassWrapper(cls):
            def __init__(self, owners=users):
                super(cls, self).__init__(owners=owners)

        ClassWrapper.__name__ = cls.__name__
        ClassWrapper.__module__ = cls.__module__

        return ClassWrapper

    return class_wrapper


class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, owners=None):
        if owners is None:
            owners = set()
        self.owners = owners

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for owner in self.owners:
            print owner,
        print


@auto_assign_perms('owner', 'user')
class Test1(Base):
    pass


@auto_assign_perms('coach')
class Test2(Base):
    pass


class Test3(Base):
    pass


t = Test1(); t.save() # owner user
t = Test2(); t.save() # coach
t = Test3(); t.save() #
```